# `go get` fails with permission denied on certain go packages

Tags: macos, go, sudo

Installing some go packages fails with `permission denied` error, eg.:

```
$ go get code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/cover
go install code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/cover: open /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/cover: permission denied
```

When I tried using `sudo` to fix the permission issue, it failed with `$GOPATH not set` error:

```
$ sudo go get code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/cover
Password:
package code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/cover: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: @3of3 both question & answer improved. Thanks for you big help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. The `godoc`, `go tool vet`, `go tool cover` etc. are special [go.tools](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse?repo=tools#hg%2Fcmd) commands that are meant to be installed into the system path by default with the go binary. If these commands are not available, you should try reinstall go itself (or find `go.tools` in your packaging system).

   Note: On OS X 10.8+, try installing go using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) instead of the official .pkg installer and your troubles should be gone (as of go 1.4):  `brew install go`
2. If you want to download a specific pkg into your `$GOPATH` (eg. 3rd party dependency), use `go get -d <pkg>` instead. Example:

   ```
   go get -d code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/cover
   ```
3. You **shouldn't** need to use the `sudo` hammer at all, as your `$GOPATH` should point to a directory that you own, and thus no `permission: denied` error at all.

   But if you really know what you're doing, and you still want to `sudo` install something, you need to edit the sudoers file first to fix the root's GOPATH:

   ```
   $ sudo visudo
   ```

   add the following line:

   ```
   Defaults    env_keep += "GOPATH"
   ```

   This will make the `sudo go get` (root context) pick up your `$GOPATH` value.

Comment: After searching through 10 similarish questions with a multitude of answers this is the only answer that completely covered everything! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this because I installed go with MacPorts.  Vojtech Vitek's answer pointed me in the right direction but I thought I would go ahead and post the literal solution I needed.

Run `sudo port install go-tools`.  I don't know why godoc et al are not included with the base go package, but whatever.